# How to do Complex Joins in Repository pattern using NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am using Repository pattern to develop my project using Nhibernate. How to do complex join in Nhibernate. I am using below repository method for fetching data

```
public virtual TEntity FindBy(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> query)
    {
        try
        {
            return NHUnitOfWork.Session.Query<TEntity>().Where(query).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Here I can fetch data without any joins. How to fetch data with joins?
for eg: Menu details are storing in Menu table and Menu Rights are storing to Menu Rights table. How to create a repository for that?

Answer (score 1):

With `QueryOver`, accepting input `Junction` instead of `Expression` to your `FindBy` method will do.

Following code may be helpful. Remove `columnList` and `top` parameters if not needed to you. Please note that my `ISession` usage is different. You need to replace `nhSession` with `NHUnitOfWork.Session`. Another difference is that you are using `Query` and I am using `QueryOver` here.

```
public virtual IList<T> FindBy<T>(ProjectionList columnList, Junction where, int top) where T : BaseEntity
{
    IList<T> instance = GetQueryOver<T>(columnList, where).Take(top).List();
    return instance;
}

public virtual IQueryOver<T> GetQueryOver<T>(ProjectionList columnList, Junction where) where T : BaseEntity
{
    IQueryOver<T> query = null;
    if((columnList != null) && (where != null))
    {
        query = nhSession.QueryOver<T>()
                .Select(columnList)
                .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<T>())
                .Where(where);
    }
    else if((columnList != null) && (where == null))
    {
        query = nhSession.QueryOver<T>()
                .Select(columnList)
                .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<T>());
    }
    else if((columnList == null) && (where != null))
    {
        query = nhSession.QueryOver<T>()
                .Where(where);
    }
    else
    {
        query = nhSession.QueryOver<T>();
    }
    return query;
}
```

And then, you can call this at some other location like:

```
Junction where = Restrictions.Conjunction();
where.Add(Restrictions.Eq(Projections.Property<MyEntity>(x => x.Field), findValue));
where.Add(Restrictions.................);
where.Add(Restrictions.................);
entityList = Repository.FindBy<MyEntity>(null, where, 100);
```

Comment: Are you sure this answer is targeted to this question? He is using `Query` not `QueryOver` and no Transformers are needed. He can just use `Select` or `ProjectTo` from AutoMapper to make Projections easier.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to eager load related entities, use `Fetch` and `FetchMany`.

```
public virtual Menu FindBy(Expression<Func<Menu, bool>> query)
{
    return NHUnitOfWork.Session.Query<Menu>().Where(query)
        .FetchMany(m => m.Rights)
        // Required with FetchMany and First, otherwise only one right would be loaded.
        .ToList()
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Or if your model has only one right per menu:

```
public virtual Menu FindBy(Expression<Func<Menu, bool>> query)
{
    return NHUnitOfWork.Session.Query<Menu>().Where(query)
        .Fetch(m => m.Right)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

But it seems you want to define some "generic repository" encapsulating the NHibernate API.
Maybe then:

```
public virtual TEntity FindBy<TFetched>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> query,
    Expression<Func<TEntity, IEnumerable<TFetched>>> fetchMany)
{
    var query = NHUnitOfWork.Session.Query<TEntity>().Where(query);
    if (fetchMany != null)
        query = query.FetchMany(fetchMany);
    return query
        // Required with FetchMany and First, otherwise only one right would be loaded.
        .ToList()
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Or if your model has only one right per menu:

```
public virtual TEntity FindBy<TFetched>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> query,
    Expression<Func<TEntity, TFetched>> fetch)
{
    var query = NHUnitOfWork.Session.Query<TEntity>().Where(query);
    if (fetch != null)
        query = query.Fetch(fetch);
    return query
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

But how to do if you need many fetches*? And sub-fetches (`ThenFetch`/`ThenFetchMany`)? It looks to me like a cursed path. You may end up coding encapsulation for the whole NHibernate API following that path.

Indeed, exposing publicly an `Expression where` argument on repositories does not look good to me. Your repository is then no more responsible of defining how the data is queried.
If you want to do that, why not exposing directly the `IQueryable`? It would prove far less code verbose than trying to encapsulate it in a "repository" while still defining the query outside of this "repository".

*: beware of Cartesian products in case you do more than one `FetchMany`. To avoid it, either split your query in many (using `ToFuture` if you wish a single round-trip to DB), or use [lazy loading with batching](/a/36070727/1178314) instead of fetching.